# Conjugacy classes of the representatives

Tags: representation-theory

I have just started reading about chracter theory. I am confused on few things like how can we find the order of a group G and Centralizer of element $g_i$ i.e $C_G(g_i)$ of a group G of the representative through character table? What is meant by $\overline{(\psi (g))}$ where $\psi$ is the character?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? You have the character table for a group and you want to find which information from this? The order of the group? And something about the conjugacy classes of some centralizer subgroups?

Comment: The order of the group is the sum, over the irreducible characters $\chi$, of $(\chi(1))^2$.

Comment: Can you be more clear about the conjugacy thing? What exactly are you trying to determine?

Comment: Actually first I want to know how we get entries of the character table, and how we find the order of that group and centeralizer of element?

Comment: How you do those things depends on what you know about the group to begin with. You might enjoy https://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/ccooper/Groups/CHAP07%20Representations%20of%20Finite%20Groups.pdf and https://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/ccooper/Groups/CHAP08%20Inducing%20Characters.pdf

Comment: Have you had a look at those links?

Comment: The material you provided is quite useful and easy to understand. Thanks @Gerry

Comment: Good. When you feel up to it, you could write up and post an answer to your question.